# How do I use triple quotes with \

Tags: python

I've just started learning Python recently, but I have written the exact same code I have watched in the course, it worked for him but didn't work for me.

```
pr =""" "Test" \ 'Test' """
```

The problem says

```
"message": "Anomalous backslash in string: '\\ '. String constant might be missing an r
```

I've really tried several ways to solve this problem, but none worked, it only works when I make a `\\`but one back slash doesn't work.

Comment: \ represents escape sequences . such as \n \t \r \\ \'  , this is used to avoid confusion for the compilers while executing the stateements

Comment: This message isn't from Python itself, but from whatever code you are calling. You'll need to show what you do with the string for people to help.

Comment: also , when i tested your code in python REPL , i got the output , not the error

Comment: Ah, I searched for the message and it probably comes from Pylint: https://codedb.app/docs/pylint-messages/w1401-anomalous-backslash-in-string.html

Answer (score 0):

you cannot use backslash alone, it's part of text syntax (for example when you try to go to the next line you use \n), so when you are using \ it search for command related to what is coming in front of it.
if you want to have a backslash in your string, all you have to do is to write it twice

for example this code will give you

```
print( """ for example \\ """ )

>>for example \
```

Comment: It's not _exactly_ true to say that you cannot use backslash alone. It works... depending on what character comes after it. But it's _inadvisable_ to use it alone exactly because it is dependent on what comes after, and can easily lead to confusion and mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

That is called **escaping**.
Python as many other programming languages has some special characters or rather combination of characters.
These characters would be, for example `\n \t` - new line and tabulation respectively.

When interpreter meets a `\` it assumes that a special character is about to appear. This is why you can't just use single `\`. So in order to be able to place a single `\` without it being treated as a beginning of a special sequence **escaping** is used.

Technique is different for different languages, but in python escaping is achieved by placing `\` before special character.
So in `\\` first `\` is used as indicator of a special sequence and thus is ignored, second `\` is what you get as a result.

So to give you more examples:

```
print('line\n another')
```

will result to

```
line

another
```

as `\n` is a newline sequence

But this:

```
print('line\\n another')
```

will result into:

```
line\n another
```

The extra `\` escaped a second `\` and `n` is left as is as it is not a part of special sequence anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for responding. The problem is now solved. I believe the problem was from the visual studio itself, I just installed an extension and rebooted the program and it worked! Now the message doesn't appear anymore.

Thank you one more time <3